# Names of Spaces - "Safari" vs [Website name]

Tags: spaces, mission-control

I use Spaces a ton.  I recently used my wife's MBA, and was surprised to see that when I put Safari into full screen and hit <kbd>F3</kbd> to show all windows and spaces, the space with Safari was identified with the name of the website.

However, on my computer (Mac Studio, Ventura 13.2.1), it just says "Safari."  I cannot figure out what the difference is.  I'd love for my computer to say the name of the active website.

Any ideas on how if there is a setting something somewhere that would effect this?

Comment: What’S  the macOS version of your wife’ MBA?

Comment: I know it's Ventura but not sure which specific release (not here right now) - but I just figured it out, see answer below.

Comment: Instead of putting SOLVED in the question title, please upvote/accept your answer below.

Comment: Done, thank you! (edit - actually, it won't let me upvote my own answer, and it says I can't accept my own answer until after 2 days.  I'll come back later!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After weeks of wondering about it and messing with it here and there, I just recently figured it out purely by accident.

If you have ***two or more***  full screen Safari windows/spaces on the same monitor, then it shows the name of the active website, rather than "Safari".